# Copy All the elements/object of one list N times to new list. Using java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-stream

Copy all the elements of one list N times in a new list.

I have list of Fruits which i want to iterate to N times and add all the value to new list but the in the list we have less then my iteration so i want to add Empty fruits with incremental id. how to do using java 8 and stream programming.
I have total 7 fruits in my current list but i want to looped in 10 time copied all data to new list and if data is not available in the index then i want to add empty object with incremental ids.
I tried but not getting expected result.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor 
public class Fruit {
   int id;
   String type;
}

List<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<>();
    fruits.add(new Fruit(1, "mango"));
    fruits.add(new Fruit(2, "grapes"));
    fruits.add(new Fruit(3, "apple"));
    fruits.add(new Fruit(4, "banana"));
    fruits.add(new Fruit(5, "papaya"));
    fruits.add(new Fruit(6, "jack fruit"));
    fruits.add(new Fruit(7, "dragon fruit"));
List<Fruit> newFruits = new ArrayList<>();

    fruits.stream().map(value -> {
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).forEach(index -> {
            if (value.equals(null))
                newFruits.add(new Fruit(index, ""));
            else
                newFruits.add(value);
        });
        return null;
    });
```

Expected OP: for newFruits

```
newFruits :
[Fruit(id=1, type=mango), 
 Fruit(id=2, type=grapes), 
 Fruit(id=3, type=apple), 
 Fruit(id=4, type=banana), 
 Fruit(id=5, type=papaya), 
 Fruit(id=6, type=jack fruit), 
 Fruit(id=7, type=dragon fruit),
 Fruit(id=8, type="").
 Fruit(id=9, type=")
 Fruit(id=10, type="")]
```

Comment: Why you want to add first arraylist data into second arraylist? It's meaningless. You consume more memory area if add first arraylist data into second arraylist

Comment: @FaeemazazBhanej Actually this is only snipped of code of my current project logic my first Arraylist is huge which i do the filter first then I want final list which have only 7 records but I want to looped in 10 times.  May be possible for second loop i do the filter first then i want final list which have only 5 records then so this case also i want looped 10 times with and add all 5 object and rest empty value to newArraylist

Comment: What if the fruit list is not sorted and the ids are not sequential?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streams might not be the right tool for this task. Why not just add all elments from original list to new list and calculate how many new entries to add after finding the largest id? Something like:

```
List<Fruit> newFruits =  new ArrayList<>();
newFruits.addAll(fruits);

int N = 10;
int toAdd = N - fruits.size();
int maxId = fruits.stream().mapToInt(Fruit::getId).max().orElse(0);

IntStream.rangeClosed(1,toAdd).forEach(i -> newFruits.add(new Fruit(maxId + i, "")));
```

Or take a look at @Holger's comment.

Comment: `int maxId = fruits.stream().mapToInt(Fruit::getId).max().orElse(0);` • `List<Fruit> newFruits = Stream.concat(fruits.stream(), IntStream.rangeClosed(1,toAdd).mapToObj(i -> newFruits.add(new Fruit(maxId + i, "")))).collect(Collectors.toList());`